# Hibernate freezing web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have Spring + Hibernate web application with cron task running daily. Problem is that when cron task is running web application pages become unresponsive and all pages just hang.

Cron task makes many database queries via hibernate, however it shouldn't make database or application unresponsive.

Hibernate integration is used like in [this Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight) suggests. Daos have @Repository and @Transactional annotations and are created with @Autowired in controllers and cron task classes.

Datasource is com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource and it has proper pool settings.

Tasks are defined with @Scheduled annotation.

What could be possible causes for this kind of problem? I know that this seems vague question, but it is really real problem. What kind of logging etc I could do to start figure out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Try turning on the hibernate logging (spring.jpa.show_sql:true , ex. in your yml spring:jpa:show_sql:true) and see what's happening in detail with each query. And let us know

Comment: generally this means absent or wrong transactional configuration. Post some code/configuration.

Comment: I found out that issue was with cron task, it had @Transactional annotation, when I removed it it started to work.